# z-index inherits parents z-index , or not?

Tags: javascript, css

I have two absolute divs.
One item on div A will show div B (on click + some javascript code). I want to have a higher Zindex on B than on A. (I want B above A)-

This item has its own zindex (lower than div A zindex). 
I thouhgt than zindex was inheritated by childrens from parents , but it seems it doesn't.

The question is ...? How can I get the 'computed' zindex for my 'item'

Comment: How about posting some code?

Answer (score 43):

No, it isn't inherited. You can see it in [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

However, be aware that `z-index` sets the z-position relatively to the stacking context. And a positioned element with non `auto` `z-index` will create an stacking context.

That means that if you have

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
<div id="c"></div>

#a, #b, #c { position: absolute; top: 0 }
#a { z-index: 1; }
#b { z-index: 1000000; }
#c { z-index: 2; }
```

Then, `#c` will overlap `#b`, even though `#b` has higher `z-index`.

Therefore, `z-index` is not technically inherited, but `z-index` of ancestors does affect z-position.

I suggest reading [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Comment: Great explanation. And since this is the best answer so far, I wanted to add to it... One thing to make explicitly clear, `z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)`. This is quoted from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a client-side debugger like Firefox's Firebug to check the computed styles:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I can't do it
I have a Z-INDEX 1 photo carousel widget
and above it a Z-INDEX 2 image
And I want to take an element out of the first widget and put it above the image.
And it does not work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33069771)