# How z-index is not working for a tooltip inside a table td when Scroll is available?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to give more left to the element "SerialNumberTooltip" and more z-index after the hover in the following thread, so that my tool-tip appear over the scroll and body. But Z-index seems not working here.

eg:

```
.SerialNumberTooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 40px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: none;
}
```

[How can I fix the position of tooltips within a scrolling <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993378/how-can-i-fix-the-position-of-tooltips-within-a-scrolling-div)

http://jsfiddle.net/vw6naxmr/

The above solution is more likely to my problem. Please help..

Comment: It's not clear, in your jsfiddle looks like z-index is working properly

Comment: Your jsfiddle code corks properly as you wanted , increase left value of class SerialNumberTooltip to make in more left

Comment: Hi Cristian, Frankely, I dont how to edit that jsfiddle. if i give more left and z index to tooltip, it is coming behind the scroll. i want to be tooltip above the scroll bar towards right.

Comment: Hi Sudarshan, Tooltip is appearing under the scroll bar. I want tooltip to be above the scroll bar towards the right.

Comment: you have to know that z-index attribute is not enough to make the element on the top if any his parent has lower z-index.. example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349394/z-index-inherits-parents-z-index-or-not

Comment: Hi Mario, I have Position Relative on Parent and absolute on Child. So only lower z-index on parent causing this issue. How i can resolve this problem? any idea?